# When I run newapkbuild in a container I get "ERROR: : Do not run abuild as root"

Tags: packaging, alpine-linux, buildah

I'm trying to containerize my build work flow. I do not run Alpine on the metal or in a VM but I do launch Alpine Containers.

When building a new Alpine package, I'm using `newapkbuild` but because I'm in a container, the container thinks it's root (though it's mapped to non-root, and the whole container is rootless). But when I run `newapkbuild`, I'm getting

```
/ # /usr/bin/newapkbuild mypackage
>>> ERROR: : Do not run abuild as root
>>> ERROR: : Do not run abuild as root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to worry about it. The error here is not fatal. It's more of a warning. Except for the warning, it does the same thing as if you were not root.